# Input of Neural Network is a matrix

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, input, neural-network, output

i need a neural network where i can put 10 inputs: the first 9 are simple numbers, the last one is a Matrix (15x15). My outputs will be the last 3 numbers. There is any way to do it without transforming the matrix into a vector? Becouse if i'll transform it in a vector i'll loose the position of my numbers, or not?
Thank you very much.

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why transforming a matrix would result in loss of position of the numbers. You can for example use numpy's flatten to get a vector in a specific order and then transform it back into a matrix using numpy's reshape, using the same order:

```
In: 
    array([[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).flatten('F').reshape((3, 2), order='F')
Out:
    array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Vectorizing data rarely hurts performance.
However, there are models for your problem as well:
https://www.mii.lt/informatica/pdf/INFO720.pdf

This model accepts purely matrix valued inputs. but it is easy to modify it by adding additional vector values input (i.e. `w'x + u'Xv`, where `x` is 9 vector and 15x15 `X` is matrix).